# jQuery each() Calling Function

Tags: jquery, validation, each

(Multiple revisions)

I have coded a validation function which validates required fields on the fly.  The over 100 required fields are identified by class="req":

```
$('.req').change (validate);
```

The validation function is rather lengthy but the gist is that it determines the type of input and, if not valid, highlights the input and shows a hidden span with error message generated from the attribute value of title of the input.  It is 100% functional.

```
function validate () {
 console.log ($(this).attr("id"));
 // does its work
}
```

When the form is submitted, I want to loop through the required fields:

```
$('#button').click ( function () {
 $('.req').each( function () { 
  console.log ($(this).attr("id"));
  validate ();
 });
});
```

Validation fails with no errors in console.  I have also tried (which also fails):

```
 $('.req').each(validate);
```

When clicking the button, console reads (short excerpt):

```
bus_name
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value>
txtphys_addr
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value>
```

It seems apparent that the change event calls the function and passes the object, while the each loop calls the function but does not pass the object.

I am at a loss.  Any suggestions?

Comment: [Quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/)

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what happens? Do you get an error? Does the page reload?

Comment: Calling `each()` as you do in your second example should maintain the scope of `this` - exactly the same as `change()` does. What errors are there in your console?

Comment: Does `validate` take any parameters?  Is `function validate () {` *exactly* what it looks like?  Or is is possibly `function validate (e) {`?

Comment: doesn't make sense to call `validate()` inside `each` with no arguments. For more help need to show what `validate() `does

Answer (score 0):

Solution found by OP:

> **Solution:**
>
> ```
> $('.req').each( function () { 
> validate.call ($(this));
> });
> ```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using this type of validation:

```
$('.specified-form input[type="submit"]').click(function(e) {
    var error =  0;
    $('.specified-form .req').each(function() {
        // validation code
    });

    if (error) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

However, in validation code you must handle the "error" variable in order to be able to submit or not.

Depends very much on how your validation code is. If you want a good answer, please paste that code here so we can modify or adapt.